# Limit Thumb to elliptic area

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, slider, area

I'm quite new to WPF so I'm learning most of this the hard (but fun) way. I'm constructing a HSV-like colorpicker usercontrol, and would like to obtain the behaviour were the thumb I use as the "selector" is limited to an elliptic area (circle actually). When moved outside, the selector should stick to the side and not move at all. I believe this is the most common GUI-behaviour, so that is how it should behave. Feel free to suggest a better behaviour!

Is there a common, known and recommended solution to this or is it up to everyone to re-invent the wheel each time?

Any good ideas of how to solve this?

Code-behind:

```
public partial class HSVColorPicker : UserControl
{
    public HSVColorPicker()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void onDragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        Canvas.SetLeft(thumb, Canvas.GetLeft(thumb) + e.HorizontalChange);
        Canvas.SetTop(thumb, Canvas.GetTop(thumb) + e.VerticalChange);
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas">
        <Image x:Name="wheel" Source="colorwheel.png" Width="300" Margin="5,5,0,0"/>
        <Thumb Name="thumb" DragDelta="onDragDelta" Canvas.Left="104" Canvas.Top="68" Template="{StaticResource thumbTemplate}" />
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

While I'm in here, the thumb is always dragging behind the cursor, is there another way to create this? As I said, I'm new to WPF and GUI-making altogether so maybe there are obvious solutions that haven't occurred to me ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some rethinking and dropped the Thumb completely, using a dummy circle (named thumb) instead. Now im listening to, mousedown, mouseup and mousemove on the canvas and determine what should be possible and not. This has the nice feature that the thumb sticks to the colorwheel edge when the mouse goes outside the area, but the area is a bit larger than the colorwheel, to make it easy to get a point on the border. Not complete but it solved my question so I post it as it is at this moment.

```
    private bool mousePressed { get; set; }
    private bool mouseWithinArea { get; set; }
    private Point circleMiddlePoint { get; set; }
    private int margin;
    private double mPX;
    private double mPY;
    private double localXpos;
    private double globalXpos
    {
        get
        {
            return localXpos + mPX;
        }
        set
        {
            localXpos = value - mPX;
            Canvas.SetLeft(thumb, value);
        }
    }
    private double localYpos;
    private double globalYpos
    {
        get
        {
            return mPY - localYpos;
        }
        set
        {
            localYpos = mPY - value;
            Canvas.SetTop(thumb, value);
        }
    }

    public HSVColorPicker()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        wheel.Width = 300;
        margin = 15;
        mPX = 150+margin;
        mPY = 150+margin;
        circleMiddlePoint = new Point(mPX, mPY);
    }

    private void CalcPosition(double X, double Y)
    {
        double radius = wheel.Width / 2.0;
        double vectorX = X - mPX;
        double vectorY = Y - mPY;
        double distance = Math.Sqrt(vectorX * vectorX + vectorY * vectorY);
        if (distance > radius)
        {
            double factor = radius / distance;
            vectorX *= factor;
            vectorY *= factor;
        }
        globalXpos = vectorX + mPX;
        globalYpos = vectorY + mPY;
    }

    private void wheel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (mouseWithinArea)
        {
            mousePressed = true;
            Point mousePoint = e.GetPosition(this);
            CalcPosition(mousePoint.X, mousePoint.Y);
        }
    }

    private void wheel_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Point mousePoint = e.GetPosition(this);
        double relX = mousePoint.X - mPX;
        double relY = mPY - mousePoint.Y;
        if (mouseWithinArea)
        {
            if (Math.Sqrt(relX * relX + relY * relY) > 150+margin)
            {
                mouseWithinArea = false;
            }
            else
            {
                if (mousePressed)
                {
                    CalcPosition(mousePoint.X, mousePoint.Y);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (Math.Sqrt(relX * relX + relY * relY) < 150+margin)
            {
                mouseWithinArea = true;
                if (mousePressed)
                {
                    CalcPosition(mousePoint.X, mousePoint.Y);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void wheel_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        mousePressed = false;
    }
}

<Canvas x:Name="canvas" Background="Transparent" MouseDown="wheel_MouseDown" MouseMove="wheel_MouseMove" MouseUp="wheel_MouseUp" Width="330" Height="330">
        <Image x:Name="wheel" Source="colorwheel.png" Width="300" Margin="15,15,0,0"  />
        <Ellipse Margin="0,0,0,0"
                x:Name="outerEll"
                Stroke="Silver"
                StrokeThickness="15" 
                Width="330"
                Height="330"/>
        <Ellipse Name="thumb" Stroke="Black" Fill="Silver" Canvas.Left="150" Canvas.Top="150" Width="15" Height="15" Margin="-12" />
    </Canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the center of your thumb to lay within your color wheel.

So, the distance between the center of your thumb and the center of your color wheel (that is, the center of your canvas) must be less than
 or equal to the radius of your color wheel (that is, half the side of your canvas).

Untested c# code:

```
void onDragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
{
    double radius = canvas.RenderSize.Width / 2.0;
    double thumbCenterX = Canvas.GetLeft(thumb) - thumb.RenderSize.Width + e.HorizontalChange;
    double thumbCenterY = Canvas.GetTop(thumb) - thumb.RenderSize.Height + e.VerticalChange;
    double colorWheelCenterX = canvas.RenderSize.Width / 2.0;
    double colorWheelCenterY = canvas.RenderSize.Height / 2.0;
    double vectorX = thumbCenterX - colorWheelCenterX;
    double vectorY = thumbCenterY - colorWheelCenterY;
    double distance = Math.Sqrt(vectorX * vectorX + vectorY * vectorY);
    if(distance > radius) {
        double factor = radius / distance;
        vectorX *= factor;
        vectorY *= factor;
    }
    Canvas.SetLeft(thumb, colorWheelCenterX + vectorX - thumb.RenderSize.Width / 2.0);
    Canvas.SetTop(thumb, colorWheelCenterY + vectorY - thumb.RenderSize.Height / 2.0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, although it does not stick unmovable to the edge while the cursor is outside, you definitely did a big chunk of the work! The thumb and the cursor also gets separated if the cursor leaves and re-enters again, so I will do some debugging and accept your answer. Will post my final solution when done.